# VSCode suddenly started executing Python scripts as a subprocess

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

Normally when I would click on "Run" button in VSCode for a Python script it would activate the currently selected virtual environment and simply call `python <script_name.py>` in the terminal and it all worked fine.

Now all of a sudden every time I try to run a script what is does is instead call a subprocess via conda like so:

`conda run -n <environment_name> --no-capture-output --live-stream python <script_name.py>`

And this new version is causing some issue because for whatever reason conda refuses to recognise some of the packages as having been installed. The code still works fine when I manually type the run command in the terminal but I want the old behaviour to be back.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Input: Ctrl + Shift + P .
Enter: Terminal: select default profile .
Change the default to CMD .
Maybe this can help you.